# Microsoft.Net.Http library conflict between MVC project and PCL

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget, portable-class-library

I am using Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries 2.2.29 for my WebApp and PCL.

Here is the link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/

PCL is using **System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll version 1.7.29** because of compatibility.

MVC project is pulling **System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll version 4.2.29** because it is compatible with 4.5 framework. It also has dependency to my PCL.

If I only build my WebApp it works fine, because it pulls 4.2.29 version. But if I build another project which depends on my PCL (for example Xamarin APP), it throws 1.7.29 version into web/bin folder and I receive following error on Web Project.

> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=4.2.29.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +234
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +108
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +25    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +34
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +49

I have following config at my web.config:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.29.0" newVersion="4.2.29.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

PCL packages.config

```
<package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
```

WebAPP packages.config

```
 <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="net451" />
```

I can remove web.config configuration to make it work with version 1.7.29. But I do not want to do this, there I would like to use latest compatible version of this library of each project.

Why VS 2015 community edition/nuget would place non-compatible/lower version of library into web/bin folder while I am building non-related project?

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You'd better ask MSBuild to give you diagnostics. Without that it is not clear who copied the old version around.

Comment: How do you set your PCL project Targets? I create a sample PCL project targets to .NET 4.5, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8 and Xamarin Android. After I install Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries 2.2.29, the System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll version is 1.5.9. And I don't set bindingRedirect in my WebApp, both of my Xamrin app and Web App could build successful. Could you share a sample project here to reproduce this issue in my side?

Comment: @Wendy please see here https://github.com/reyou/CrossLibraryReference download this project and first build web app and check bin folder then build class library 2 and check bin folder again. Try with VS 2015 community edition if possible please. Here is my experience: https://github.com/reyou/CrossLibraryReference/tree/master/debugImages this time it happened over "System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll"

Comment: For your sample solution, it works fine in my side. Both of the Http.Extensions.dll and Http.Primitives.dll are use the high version in Web project and ClassLibrary2 project. I build the Web app first, and then reference the ClassLibrary2 in Web app and build again. The dll version are the same. Is there something wrong with my steps? And I also don't find the <bindingRedirect> node in your Web.config file. Please check your sample solution, whether there has anything missing.

Comment: @Wendy I will try to make video recording for steps I am taking. Simply what I will do, clone git repo, open with vs 2015 CE, build web app, check web/bin folder for "System.Net.xxx" reference versions. Then build Class Library 2 and check again in web/bin folder for "System.Net.xxx" reference versions.

Comment: I have reproduce the System.Net.XXX version issue in my side, but I don't get the error message that in Web app.

Comment: Yes because I did not include reference redirection in web.config. If you do that, it will not find target library and fail. Anyway, regardless of that, why Class Library 2 would override .dll in Web Folder? Is this a bug?

Comment: Have you tried with https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Build/? Mode description for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824804/what-does-the-microsoft-bcl-build-nuget-package-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not a proven solution but, I had to remove projects from solution one by one and add back in. Then I re-mapped project dependencies by right clicking on projects and choosing dependencies on them. It seems like working right now. It might be a problem with VS build order when more than 3 projects are cross referencing each other.