# Deploying service fabric Visual studio build failing

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to run the "Visual studio build task" in VSTS CI, but its failing with the following error:

[Build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzcDQ.jpg)

I read it here [bclbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824804/what-does-the-microsoft-bcl-build-nuget-package-do)[What does the Microsoft.Bcl.Build NuGet package do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824804/what-does-the-microsoft-bcl-build-nuget-package-do)

and passed the MSBuild arguments as /p:BclBuildImported=Ignore but still it complains that nuget restore didn't occur. What could be the problem?

Nuget restore task:

[Nuget-restore task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nuKd.png)

Comment: Have you restored the Nuget packages during the build? Can you build the project locally with VS?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure you can build the project locally with VS. Then add `Nuget Restore` task in the build definition to restore the packages.

---

**UPDATE:**

Just check your `Nuget.config` file, make sure you have set the correct `feeds/package sources` you want to consume and the package `Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21` is included in the sources.

See [Specifying sources in NuGet.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/packages/nuget-restore?view=vsts#specifying-sources-in-nugetconfig) for details.

Besides, you can also try to create a new build definition with the Nuget restore task, then provide the `nuget.config` file and proper path to solution, also try with other Hosted agents.

[image]

Comment: I have created the nuget restore task,

Comment: please take a look at the image attached in the above post. just now i posted that task's screen shot.

Comment: @AshutoshKumar Just check your `Nuget.config` file, make sure you have set the correct `feeds/package sources` you want to consume and the package `Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21` is included in the sources. See [Specifying sources in NuGet.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/packages/nuget-restore?view=vsts#specifying-sources-in-nugetconfig) for details.

Comment: Thanks i will check and try building again.

Comment: @AshutoshKumar Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: This problem is solved now, thanks for the help, i created a fresh task and gave feeds to use: Feeds in my nuget.config. Gave the proper path to solution and it built. The project was building fine in the local. I also changed Host to Host VS2017